# Does jQuery UI work with both branches of jQuery? 1.0 and 2.0?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm just confused as to why the jQuery UI documentation uses the 1.0 branch of jQuery ... is that required for jQuery UI to function properly? Or can I use the jQuery 2.0 branch (currently 2.1.4) together with jQuery UI?

Thank you.

Comment: jQueryUI 1.9+ will work with any version of jQuery from 1.6+ [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery ui will work on Jquery versions above 1.6 ..
you can check it in jqueryui website's download options [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: Yes but one could easily assume that 1.6+ is referring to the 1.X branch of jQuery, and not the 2.X branch.